# Redirect to New Website

Tags: php, .htaccess

I made two folders in root called "oldwebsite" and "newwebsite".

Suppose domain is `www.example.com`

If someone goes to `www.example.com` it has to go to index on the root folder, 
else if someone goes to `www.example.com/newwebsite` it has to go to folder `newwebsite`, 
else all other has to go to `www.example.com/oldwebsite`

Please let me know how to redirect from root either using htaccess or php.

old website `www.example.com`

if in google shows `www.example.com/forum1`
new website `www.folder1.example.com`

Comment: Sorry but I really dont get this if the 2 answers down here aren't right. This isn't really good formulated.

Comment: Do you means I have to edit for more clear explaination ?? I think its clear. Please let me know so that I can modify

Comment: Nevermind. Might be my bad but I really didn't get it. I see it's solved so dont mind me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this in .htaccess file in the root folder itself.

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
Redirect /newwebsite http://www.example.com/newwebsite/index.html
Redirect /oldwebsite http://www.example.com/oldwebsite/index.html
```

Comment: Hello SRC, the first two lines are fine. The third line, instead of specifying /oldwebsite, can we forward all the links there. I means if not line1 or line2 go to line3. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Another method of doing this is creating an index.php in your root directory:

```
<?php
header("Location: /newwebsite/");
?>
```

Comment: I think you miss understood. if someone click www.example.com it has to go to index page on the root folder and if someone click www.example.com/newwebsite it has to go to index of the newwebsite folder and rest all i want to divert to www.example.com/oldwebsite

Answer (score 0):

Try this
php have header and redirect to page navaigate.

```
<?php

header("Location: www.example.com/newwebsite/");

//or


Redirect('http://www.example.com/newwebsite');
?>
```